# question related spark broadcast join with RDD and broadcast RDD.collectAsMap() while doing triangle computation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanna compute the count of triangle problem, where my input is follower, followee. I use broadcast join to compute this triangle, set edges to `edges.collectAsMap()` to broadcast to all nodes.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Combining in Spark")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
val edgesRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile(args(0))
  .map(line => {
    val parts = line.split(",")
    (parts(0).toInt, parts(1).toInt)  // (follower, user)
  })
  .filter { case (follower, user) => follower < maxValue && user < maxValue }

val broadcastEdges = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(edgesRDD.collectAsMap())

val trianglesRDD = edgesRDD
  .flatMap { case (a, b) =>
    broadcastEdges.value.get(b) match {
      case Some(c) if broadcastEdges.value.contains(c) && broadcastEdges.value(c)             == a => Seq((a, b, c))
      case _ => Seq.empty
    }
  }

val triangleCount = trianglesRDD.count() / 3
```

what could be the problem with this code?

My input data is `1,2 2,3 2,4, 3,1`. And my output should be `(1,2,3) (2,1,3)` and `(3,1,2)` since these 3 nodes can get circled. But I only get `(2,3,1)`, whereas if my input data is `1,2 2,3 2,4 4,1`, I can get the correct outputs which are `(1,2,4) (2,1,4) (2,4,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Collect as map for input `1 -> 2 : 2 -> 3 : 2 -> 4 : 3 ->1`

```
edgesRDD.collectAsMap()  =>  Map(2 -> 4, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1)
```

You want it to look like

```
Map(2 -> 3, 1 -> 2, 3 -> 1)
```

Map key `2` appears twice in your input, hence it overrides `2 -> 3` to `2 ->4` which breaks the connection. If you remove the input pair `(2,4)` or move it up in the order before `(2,3)`, then it should work.

In the 2nd case, for input `1,2 2,3 2,4 4,1` the `(2,4)` appears after `(2,3)` so overrides still  maintains the connection.Final map looks like

```
Map(2 -> 4, 4 -> 1, 1 -> 2)
```

Hence it works fine.